# Automate python script mac

Tags: macos, python, osx-mountain-lion, cron, crontab

I want to set up a python script to run every weekday(not sunday and saturday) on my mac OSX 10.8.4.
From what I have found so far, it looks like I want to use cron. But before I do something horrible to my computer can someone please confirm this will do what I want?

```
>>> crontab -e
>>> 30 4 * * 1-5 python /Users/lego90511/PycharmProjects/Stock Scanner/stock_scanner.py
```

If this some how does work please tell me, how can I then remove it from chron?

Answer (score 1):

That should work, but replace `Stock Scanner` with `Stock\ Scanner`. You can undo the changes by running `crontab -e` and just deleting the line. If you haven't changed `EDITOR` and you don't know how to use `vi`, you can use `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`.

So basically run `crontab -e` (or `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`) and add a line like this:

```
30 4 * * 1-5 python ~/PycharmProjects/Stock\ Scanner/stock_scanner.py
```

The crontab format is described in `man 5 crontab`.

Using launchd, you could save a plist like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>test</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>python</string>
    <string>/Users/lego90511/PycharmProjects/Stock Scanner/stock_scanner.py</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>2</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>3</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>5</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>30</integer>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then load the plist by running `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist` or by logging out and back in. You can apply changes to the plist by unloading and loading it.

Note that both cron and launchd use a 24-hour clock. If you meant 4 PM instead of 4 AM, replace the hour values with 16.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/).

This is an app I use for all of my automation needs. I highly recommend it.

Comment: The link to hazel above is dead.