# launchctl plist file not running

Tags: macos, mac, python, automation, launchctl

I have created a python script, I would like it to run on my mac some time after 4:30 every weekday. I followed the instructions a launchctl plist file [here](https://superuser.com/questions/645670/automate-python-script-mac). But it doesn't run, I looked for solutions I found one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370901/very-simple-launchd-plist-not-running-my-script)(the second answer), it didn't have an the +x, so I added it, and still nothing. I will admit I know scarcely little about automation, so how do I get this to run, and if you are feeling generous, where did you learn about automation?

Comment: Did you mean 4:30 AM or 4:30 PM in the first question? If you meant 4:30 PM, change the hour values from 4 to 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give [cron](http://www.cronmaker.com/) a try. With this tool you can execute your script.

You can use crontab.

1. Open a new Terminal
2. Type `sudo crontab -e`
3. Type `i` to go into vim's insert-mode.
4. type your cron job. This will fire your script every weekday(MON-FRI) at 4:30

   `0 30 4 ? * MON-FRI * python /path/to/your/script.py`
5. Press esc to exit vim's insert mode
6. Type ZZ (has to be capital)

If you want to change the fire-date/time, you can visit [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/). It will generate you the cron-syntax.

(You can also use launchd, but launchd is backward-compatible, so you can easily use cron without problem)

Comment: The `0 30 4 ? * MON-FRI *` format is not supported by the cron that comes with OS X (Vixie cron), but you can use `30 4 * * 1-5` instead.

Comment: Could you please explain the difference particularly the ? * to * *