# Automating python script on a mac not running

Tags: mac, python, automation, crontab, launchd

I have tried to have this question answered twice now([1](https://superuser.com/questions/645670/automate-python-script-mac), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/654120/launchctl-plist-file-not-running)). While both were informative none of the solutions have worked, and I don't know why. The first solution was to use launchctl the second was to use crontab. Neither one produced any sort of results, the script wasn't run, and there is no indication of an error, just nothing.

I am trying to run a python script at `/Users/lego90511/PycharmProjects/Stock\ Scanner/stock_scanner.py` 
I can go to the terminal and run `python /Users/lego90511/PycharmProjects/Stock\ Scanner/stock_scanner.py` and it runs just fine, I open up Pycharm and it runs fine there. I want to run it on my mac, osx 10.8.5 at 4:30pm every weekday, but for what ever reason cannot have my mac do it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use cron as per your first attempt. But this time do two things. Use an absolute path for the python binary (or declare a path variable in the header). And have the output of the cron job spit out to a file so that you can see what's going wrong.

So something like:

`30 4 * * 1-5 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Users/lego90511/PycharmProjects/Stock\ Scanner/stock_scanner.py >> /tmp/cron.out`

You should be able to see what's going wrong by reading the output in /tmp/cron.out

Hope that helps.

Comment: Alright I'm giving it a spin, we'll know in 27 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using absolute path to your python executable ?
And did you look up the logs for errors ?

Comment: How do I check the logs for automation